# Tessart4j on unix machine

Tags: java, unix, tesseract, ghostscript

I am using tess4j.jar to extract text from scanned PDF file (OCR files) in my java application.It is working fine with gsdll32.dll,liblept168.dll,libtesseract302.dll on windows machine. Now i have to deploy my java application on windows machine ,there i can't depend on .dll files . Is there any way to workout tess4j on unix machine.

Answer (score 0):

Download Tesseract [source](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/checkout) and [compile](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/Compiling) it. Tess4J will work with the built shared library objects.